# Create a tab navigator (react-navigator) with data saved in redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm trying to create a tab navigator in my React Native app with createMaterialTopTabNavigator, however I need the number of tabs to be defined by a variable that I'm saving in redux. I don't know the number of tabs there will be, as the user defines that. The redux variable is an array, so should be one tab for each array object. How can I do that?

Right know I have two tabs in my Component, here's the code. As I said, I need to change that to make it depend on the redux variable (each object in that array has some information I have to pass to the child component).

Thank you very much, guys!

```
const ProfileNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
   Screen1: {
        screen: props => <ScreenHolder screenProps={props.screenProps}  />,
        navigationOptions: {title: "Screen1"}
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: props => <ScreenHolder screenProps={props.screenProps}/>,
       navigationOptions: {title: "Screen2"}
    }
    },{
        tabBarPosition: 'top',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
})
export default createAppContainer(ProfileNavigator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use redux state importing the store in your tab navigator file:

```
import { store } from './src/store/index'
```

then you can use :

```
store.getState();
```

Although I am saying this, I often find myself avoiding using store outside the react component lifecycle, and even more not using props or changes over time to define navigation parameters directly.

I use navigation setParams though.